# Reducer don not working on redux react js

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

The state Selectedlan don't update on the click.. I think it is an error of reducer. Specifically when I the function handleGreeceLan is called the action should be called and the reducer but I think only the action is called

The file that I make the call

```
import { changeLanGR, changeLanEN }  from '../actions/toolbarActions';
  const handleGreeceLan = () => {
    changeLanGR();

  };

  const handleUKLan = () => {
     changeLanEN();
  };

<MenuItem onClick={handleUKLan}>
        ...
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleGreeceLan}>
      ...
      </MenuItem>
...
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { Selectedlan: state.Selectedlan };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { changeLanGR, changeLanEN }
)(Language);
```

Reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { LAN_GR, LAN_EN }  from '../actions/types';

const selectLanguage = (state = LAN_GR, action) => {
  if (action.type === LAN_GR) {
    return { ...state, Selectedlan: LAN_GR};
  }
  else if (action.type === LAN_EN) {
    return { ...state, Selectedlan: LAN_EN};
  }
  return state;
};

export default combineReducers({
  Selectedlan: selectLanguage
});
```

Action

```
import { LAN_GR, LAN_EN } from './types';

export const changeLanGR = () => {
 return {
   type: LAN_GR
 };
};

export const changeLanEN = () => {
 return {
   type: LAN_EN
 };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mapping the dispatch function to *props*, meaning you need to call those functions mapped from props:

```
const Language = ({ 
  className, 
  changeLanGR, 
  changeLanEN,
  ...rest 
}) => {
  const handleGreeceLan = () => {
    changeLanGR();
  };

  const handleUKLan = () => {
     changeLanEN();
  };
```

Comment: It is like this -- > const Language = ({ className, ...rest }) => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const [lan, setLan] = React.useState('EN');

  const handleMenu = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleGreeceLan = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    setLan('ΕΛ');
    changeLanGR();

  };
....

Comment: Ah, so then it's likely `rest.changLanGR()`. Or you could destructure it out specifically

Comment: Updated to explicitly destructure those out of the props argument